# Best practice to apply location filters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I would like to have a cleaner code to make filters over the initial set of values.

This code is working but is very ugly, and the problem is that I can't find a way to create a linq expression for the `splitKeywords.Contains(ks.Name)` to something like `keywordsAddressIds.Where(splitKeywords.Contains(ks.Name))`:

```
    var addressPTQuery = _addressPTRepository.Query;
    var categoryQuery = _categoryRepository.Query; 
    var keywordSearchQuery = _keywordSearchRepository.Query;

    // Initial value of keywordsAddressIds //
    var keywordsAddressIds = from ks in keywordSearchQuery where splitKeywords.Contains(ks.Name) select ks.Keyword.Addresses.Select(k => k.Id);

    var searchResults = new CategoryGetAllBySearchListDto();

    if (isUserCenter)
    {
        // Filter to keywordsAddressIds  //

        DbGeography centerPoint = Map.CreatePoint(userLng, userLat);

        // radius is in kms so we have to x 100 to get meters
        ks.Keyword.Addresses.Select(ad => ad.Id) == addressPTQuery.Where(p => p.Location.Distance(centerPoint) < radius * 1000).Select(adPT => adPT.Id));

        keywordsAddressIds = from ks in keywordSearchQuery
                             where splitKeywords.Contains(ks.Name)
                             select ks.Keyword.Addresses.Where(p => p.Location.Distance(centerPoint) < radius * 1000).Select(a => a.Id);
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
    {
        // Filter to keywordsAddressIds  //

        string locationStandard = CleanLocation(location);

        addressPTQuery = addressPTQuery.Where(p => p.PTCouncil.NameStandard == locationStandard);

        keywordsAddressIds = from ks in keywordSearchQuery
                             where splitKeywords.Contains(ks.Name)
                             select ks.Keyword.Addresses.Select(a => a.Id).Intersect(addressPTQuery.Select(ad => ad.Id));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So why you don't get all address ids and then select what you want like this

```
var addressPTQuery = _addressPTRepository.Query;
var categoryQuery = _categoryRepository.Query; 
var keywordSearchQuery = _keywordSearchRepository.Query;

// Initial value of keywordsAddresses //
var keywordsAddresses = from ks in keywordSearchQuery 
                        where splitKeywords.Contains(ks.Name) 
                        select ks.Keyword.Addresses;

var searchResults = new CategoryGetAllBySearchListDto();

if (isUserCenter)
{
    // Filter to keywordsAddressIds  //

    DbGeography centerPoint = Map.CreatePoint(userLng, userLat);

    // radius is in kms so we have to x 100 to get meters
    ks.Keyword.Addresses.Select(ad => ad.Id) == addressPTQuery.Where(p => p.Location.Distance(centerPoint) < radius * 1000).Select(adPT => adPT.Id));

    keywordsAddressIds = from p in keywordsAddresses 
                         where p.Location.Distance(centerPoint) < radius * 1000
                         select p.Id;
}
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
{
    // Filter to keywordsAddressIds  //

    string locationStandard = CleanLocation(location);

    addressPTQuery = addressPTQuery.Where(p => p.PTCouncil.NameStandard == locationStandard);

    keywordsAddressIds = from a in keywordsAddresses
                         join b in addressPTQuery on a.Id equals b.Id
                         select a.Id;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks! But is there a cleaner way to build an initial query and apply filter if necessary just with one line of code? Thanks

Comment: So in this sample you get all adresses and apply filter with one line `where` what is not clear?

Comment: I was thinking if it's not possible using a base Query and only apply a Query.Where for the 2 eventual filters

Comment: Any idea how we can achieve it?

Comment: what the sample does not correspond to what you want? in this we have first query for `keywordsAddresses` and then only apply `where` and `select`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42193/discussion-between-grundy-and-patrick)